# Frame overlapping with toolbar

Tags: pyqt, pyqt6

I have a toolbar in a main window. I want to dynamically add frames, each with their own layout. Clicking a toolbar action would hide all frames and only show the one that corresponds to the toolbar action that was clicked.

The problem: as seen on the screenshot, the frame overlaps with the toolbar. Why is this happening? I've tried adding a spacer after creating a toolbar but that didn't help.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    """ Main application window """
    def __init__(self, settings):
        try:
            QMainWindow.__init__(self)
            self.settings_window = None
            self.settings = settings

            self.setMinimumSize(QSize(700, 700))
            self.setWindowTitle("Titan Quest Modding Advanced - TQMA")

            toolbar = QToolBar("Main toolbar")
            self.addToolBar(toolbar)
            self.layout().addItem(QSpacerItem(20, 20))

            settings_action = QAction("Settings", self)
            settings_action.setStatusTip("Edit settings")
            settings_action.triggered.connect(self.get_settings_window)
            toolbar.addAction(settings_action)

            for frame_name in ["Mod merge", "Mod manager"]:

                frame = QFrame(self, objectName=frame_name)
                layout = QVBoxLayout(frame)
                test_button = QPushButton(frame_name, self)
                layout.addWidget(test_button)
                frame.setLayout(layout)
                frame.hide()

                frame_action = QAction(frame_name, self)
                frame_action.setStatusTip(frame_name)
                frame_action.triggered.connect(
                    lambda checked, frame_name=frame_name: self.show_frame_by_name(frame_name)
                )
                toolbar.addAction(frame_action)

                self.layout().addWidget(frame)

        except Exception as exc:
            traceback_formatted = traceback.format_exc()
            logger.info(traceback_formatted)
            raise RuntimeError(traceback_formatted) from exc

    def get_settings_window(self):
        """ Generates and shows settings window from which the settings can be edited """
        self.settings_window = SettingsWindow(self.settings)
        self.settings_window.setWindowModality(Qt.WindowModality.ApplicationModal)
        self.settings_window.show()

    def show_frame_by_name(self, frame_name):
        """ Takes a frame name as an input parameter. Searches main window for that frame and returns it """
        frames_to_hide = self.findChildren(QFrame)
        for frame in frames_to_hide:
            frame.hide()
        frame_to_show = self.findChild(QFrame, frame_name)
        logger.debug(f"Found frame: {frame_to_show}")
        if frame_to_show:
            frame_to_show.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The frames need to be added to the layout of the central widget.

Comment: You cannot set a layout on QMainWindow, as it has its own, private one. If you run your program in a terminal or prompt you'll clearly see multiple warnings about that. You must use a central widget. Also, use QStackedWidget instead of manually hiding/showing frames. Simply put: use a QStackedWidget to manage the frames, and set it as central widget of the main window.